# elasticsearch-logstash : parent-child mapping

Tags: java, json, postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

I have 2 postgres tables
Student which has fields (student_id,student_name)
Book which has fields (book_id,book_name,student)
The table book has a foreign key which is the primary key of the student table (student_id) in a many to one relationship (a student has many books but a book is owned by only one student).
Now I want to index this data in elastic search using logstash.
How can I establish this parent-child relationship using logstash and elasticsearch?
Can someone please describe the steps in details ?